# Como pegar o título de uma imagem por JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Como pegar o título de uma imagem e exibir num `alert`?

Comment: Onde está o título? No seu HTML? Por favor inclua o html na pergunta.

Answer (score 9):

você só precisa selecionar a imagem (seja pelo ID ou outro seletor), então acesse a propriedade `title`.

```js
var outraDiv = document.getElementById("outra-div");
var imagem = document.getElementById("imagem");
imagem.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    outraDiv.textContent = imagem.title;
});
```

```html
<div id="outra-div"></div>
<img id="imagem" src="http://image005.flaticon.com/1/svg/72/72716.svg" title="Award" />
```

Comment: Entendi, e se no caso eu quiser pegar o titulo, só quando a imagem for clicada, e depois exibir esse titulo numa div, por exemplo.

Comment: @ThiagoSilva, neste caso você tambem vai precisar pegar esta div por algum seletor, então adicione um event listener a imagem, durante o evento você atualiza o conteúdo da div.

Comment: tem como você postar o exemplo de um código do tipo, pois não manjo muito de javascript. Agradeço

Comment: @ThiagoSilva, já havia atualizado a reposta com o codigo solicitado a 23 horas

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode fazer inline

```
<div id="div"></div>
<img src="" id="imagem" onclick="document.getElementById('div').innerHTML=this.title" title="título" />
```

E se tiver muitas divs pode fazer por função

```
 <script> 
function titulo(div,titulo) {
 document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=titulo; } 
</script>

 <div id="div"></div> <img src="" id="imagem" onclick="titulo('div',
 this.title)" title="título" />
```